# I can't get the points in my game to add up

Tags: python

I am making a guessing game and I can't get the score to say anything but 0

I googled it and it came up with a formula that didn't work, so I came here.

Just in case the code looks weird, here's a link:
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user46_Rn6mbqc2fxzXniV.py

```
import random

totalScore = 0


lp = input ('Lets play the guessing game! \nPress Enter to start')
if (lp== ""):
    print ("Score\n_____")

x1 = int(input("No.1 Type a number between 0 and 5"))
if (x1 !=(random.randint(0,5))):
    input("Incorrect   :/\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+0")
    score = totalScore + 0
else:
    input("Correct!\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+1")
x2 = int(input("No.2 Type a number between 0 and 10"))
if (x2 !=(random.randint(0,10))):
    input("Incorrect   :/\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+0")
    score = totalScore + 0
else:
    input ("Correct!\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+1")
    score = totalScore + 1

x3 = int(input("No.1 Type a number between 0 and 15"))
if (x3 !=(random.randint(0,15))):
    input("Incorrect   :/\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+0")
    score = totalScore + 0
else:
    input ("Correct!\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+1")
    score = totalScore + 1

x4 = int(input("No.1 Type a number between 0 and 20"))
if (x4 !=(random.randint(0,20))):
    input("Incorrect   :/\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+0")
    score = totalScore + 0
else:
    input ("Correct!\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+1")
    score = totalScore + 1

x5 = int(input("No.1 Type a number between 0 and 25"))
if (x5 !=(random.randint(0,25))):
    input("Incorrect   :/\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+0")
    score = totalScore + 0
else:
    input ("Correct!\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+1")
    score = totalScore + 1

totalScore = score

print ("Total Score:")
print (totalScore)
```

I am trying to get the game to add all points earned and show them at the end.

Comment: There is no need for the `score` variable. If they guess correctly simply add 1 to `totalScore` else do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you are setting `score` to 0, you are overwriting the previous `score`. What you want to do instead of `score = totalScore + 1` (or 0) is simply `totalScore += 1`  (same as `totalScore = totalScore + 1`)

```
import random

totalScore = 0


lp = input ('Lets play the guessing game! \nPress Enter to start')
if (lp== ""):
    print ("Score\n_____")

x1 = int(input("No.1 Type a number between 0 and 5"))
if (x1 !=(random.randint(0,5))):
    input("Incorrect   :/\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+0")
else:
    input("Correct!\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+1")
    totalScore += 1
x2 = int(input("No.2 Type a number between 0 and 10"))
if (x2 !=(random.randint(0,10))):
    input("Incorrect   :/\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+0")
else:
    input ("Correct!\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+1")
    totalScore += 1

x3 = int(input("No.1 Type a number between 0 and 15"))
if (x3 !=(random.randint(0,15))):
    input("Incorrect   :/\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+0")
else:
    input ("Correct!\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+1")
    totalScore += 1

x4 = int(input("No.1 Type a number between 0 and 20"))
if (x4 !=(random.randint(0,20))):
    input("Incorrect   :/\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+0")
else:
    input ("Correct!\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+1")
    totalScore += 1

x5 = int(input("No.1 Type a number between 0 and 25"))
if (x5 !=(random.randint(0,25))):
    input("Incorrect   :/\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+0")
else:
    input ("Correct!\n Press Enter to move on")
    print ("+1")
    totalScore += 1

print ("Total Score:")
print (totalScore)
```

Example output:

```
Score
_____
+1
+0
+1
+0
+0
Total Score:
2
```

In the example above I also removed the superfluous `score = totalScore + 0` as adding 0 to a integer does nothing.

Thanks for the codeskulptor link to make working with the code super easy!